# What are the essential differences between the BSD and MIT licences?

Tags: mit, bsd, license-comparison, license

There are many articles out there which cover the topic in length and breadth, but so far I haven't found a nice, concise answer to the question.

What are the most important differences between the BSD and the MIT licenses and in what way do their intended uses specifically differ?

Comment: Guys we have a discussion in meta about this... we agreed questions like this are okay did we not?

Comment: [discussion on meta](http://meta.opensource.stackexchange.com/q/173/168), which seems to be leaning towards allowing this question. (Because BSD and MIT are both quite short as far as licenses go, otherwise it would need to be narrowed down more.)

Comment: vote to close because it's too useful and helpful

Answer (score 188, accepted):

When talking about BSD license, you have to be aware that there is not one, but actually four different BSD licenses. The most basic is the **zero-clause BSD** license which is basically a public domain license. It doesn't even require attribution:

> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted.

Then we have the **two-clause BSD** license:

> Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
> modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions are met:

> 1. Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright notice, this    list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
> 2. Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,    this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
>    documentation    and/or other materials provided with the
>    distribution.

The **three-clause BSD** license adds this clause:

> Neither the name of the [organization] nor the
> names of its contributors may be used to endorse or promote products
> derived from this software without specific prior written permission.

And the **four-clause BSD** license also this clause:

> All advertising materials mentioning features or use of this software
> must display the following acknowledgement:
> This product includes software developed by the [organization].

The **MIT license** does not contain any clauses regarding promotion and advertising material but does have an attribution clause, so it is most similar to the 2-clause BSD license:

> Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

> The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

So what both the 2-clause BSD license and the MIT license have in common are:

- Permits use
- Permits redistribution
- Permits redistribution with modification
- Provision to retain the copyright notice and warranty disclaimer

In addition the MIT license also explicitly allows:

- merging
- publishing
- sublicensing
- selling

However, all these freedoms are implied by the BSD license, because all these activities can be considered "use" and/or "redistribution" of the software.

The practical differences between the 2-clause BSD license and the MIT license are marginal. Which one to pick is mostly up to personal taste. Especially considering that both licenses are considered compatible, so you can take code under one license and use it in a project under the other, as long as you keep the license text around.

Comment: To me, the biggest difference is the existence of three BSD licenses and one MIT license. In order to avoid fragmentation/doubt I prefer MIT.

Comment: Partially incorrect: sublicensing is not permitted by the BSD license but the other terms (merging, publishing, selling) are permitted by the BSD license. Sublicensing is an important "freedom" as it would allow you to add another license that implies restrictions (e.g. the GPL). Ad the BSD license does not permit sublicensing, you cannot add the GPL restrictions to the code.

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/122008/7525 says "BSD-licensed projects can be used/redistributed in MIT-licensed projects.
FALSE MIT license allows for distribution without contribution credits; BSD doesn't."  Do you disagree?

Comment: @AbhiBeckert: Actually it is the other way around. “BSD-2-clause” is unique. But there are various licenses that MIT has used, so the classical MIT license is sometimes written as “MIT/Expat” to make that distinction clear. Therefore I find BSD-2-clause easier to understand

Comment: @schily: GNU [lists BSD-2-clause and BSD-3-clause as compatible with the GPL](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html). Therefore sublicensing must be included.

Comment: A claim based on a false claim is a false claim. The legal state is: if a license does not explicitly allow sub-licensing, it is forbidden - ask a lawyer.

Comment: @schily: That's an interesting take.
However, take a look at: https://github.com/jashkenas/lil-license/issues/5#issuecomment-331166081
"In short — a sublicense of an OSS project can only restrict the rights of what you can already do under the original license, and since you're required to include the original license, it's redundant to boot."
More info from a lawyer blog: https://writing.kemitchell.com/2016/09/21/MIT-License-Line-by-Line.html .
I think we're safe with BSD.

Comment: @shily: You wrote "As the BSD license does not permit sublicensing, you cannot add the GPL restrictions to the code."
That's like saying "As the BSD license does not permit sublicensing, you cannot make the code proprietary". Making a code proprietary is also adding restrictions to the code. But obviously you can.

Comment: @schily: This is another interesting food for thoughts: https://flylib.com/books/en/4.467.1.50/1/ :

"The fact that the MIT license is sublicensable is an advantage for anyone who wants to distribute copies or derivative works of MIT-licensed works. A distributor can provide to his customers all the rights needed to the entire work without expecting those customers to follow the chain of title to its beginning. "

Comment: One thing not mentioned here: the BSD4 license is definitely not GPL compatible because of the advertising clause.

Comment: I propose that the MIT license is more like the BSD 3-clause license than the 2-clause license. For my own OSS works, I use the 3-clause BSD license because the prohibition on using the name of the organization and/or contributor(s) to promote a derivative work is explicit.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray: "I propose that the MIT license is more like the BSD 3-clause license". Why do you propose that? The MIT license text as far as I can tell does not mention anything about restrictions on endorsement/promotion, but the 3rd BSD clause mentions this.

Answer (score 29):

A couple of things were not mentioned in the accepted answer:

- documentation associated with the software
- community adoption
- BSD-2-Clause Plus Patent aka "BSD+Patent"

## Documentation

Another difference between the BSD licenses and the MIT license is how they deal with the meaning of "software". 
MIT applies to the documentation associated with the software, BSD doesn't.

In MIT license, the word "Software" with a capital "S" is explicitly defined as being ["this software and associated documentation files"](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/6545/is-the-mit-license-suitable-for-documentation). In the BSD licenses, they talk about "source code and binary form", no mention of documentation.

In fact, FreeBSD uses a complete [different license for its documentation](https://www.freebsd.org/copyright/freebsd-doc-license.html).

Both MIT and BSD allow you to release your documentation under another license, that's potentially more restrictive. It is what [Symfony](https://symfony.com/license) does with MIT+[CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en).

If you want to be liberal with your documentation as well, you'd probably want to pick MIT instead of BSD. It avoids you to have to choose another documentation-specific license like [CC-BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/deed.en) or equivalent on top of your BSD licensed source code.

**EDIT:**
I want to mitigate a little bit this assertion. I Am Not A Lawyer. [Choose A License](https://choosealicense.com/non-software/), the GitHub initiative, suggests that any open source software license is suitable for documentation:

> Any open source software license or open license for media (see above)
>   also applies to software documentation. If you use different licenses
>   for your software and its documentation, be sure to specify that
>   source code examples in the documentation are also licensed under the
>   software license.

[Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/license/) is an example of widespread BSD-licensed project that also applies BSD to its documentation:

> This license applies to all files in the Flask repository and source
>   distribution. This includes Flask’s source code, the examples, and
>   tests, as well as the documentation.

## Community adoption

The NPM package manager contains libraries [mostly released under MIT](https://choosealicense.com/community/). So using it as well for your NPM package will most likely grant you more adoption.

Similarly, if you're looking to work closely with the [FreeBSD project](https://github.com/freebsd/freebsd/blob/master/COPYRIGHT) for example, you'd rather use one of the BSD licenses.

It's easier for your work to be accepted by a community when its license is already widely used within this very same community.

Let's face it though, [MIT is in general more popular](https://github.blog/2015-03-09-open-source-license-usage-on-github-com/).

## BSD-2-Clause Plus Patent aka "BSD+Patent"

There is another relatively new OSI-approved BSD license which @Philipp didn't talk about: [BSD-2-Clause Plus Patent](https://opensource.org/licenses/BSDplusPatent), also referred as [BSD-2-Clause-Patent](https://spdx.org/licenses/BSD-2-Clause-Patent.html) or "BSD+Patent".
BSD+Patent is exactly the same as BSD-2-Clause, except that BSD+Patent contains the explicit patent grant of the Apache License v2:

> Subject to the terms and conditions of this license, each copyright
>   holder and contributor hereby grants to those receiving rights under
>   this license a perpetual, worldwide, non-exclusive, no-charge,
>   royalty-free, irrevocable (except for failure to satisfy the
>   conditions of this license) patent license to make, have made, use,
>   offer to sell, sell, import, and otherwise transfer this software,
>   where such license applies only to those patent claims, already
>   acquired or hereafter acquired, licensable by such copyright holder or
>   contributor that are necessarily infringed by:
>
> (a) their Contribution(s) (the licensed copyrights of copyright
>   holders and non-copyrightable additions of contributors, in source or
>   binary form) alone; or
>
> (b) combination of their Contribution(s) with the work of authorship
>   to which such Contribution(s) was added by such copyright holder or
>   contributor, if, at the time the Contribution is added, such addition
>   causes such combination to be necessarily infringed. The patent
>   license shall not apply to any other combinations which include the
>   Contribution.
>
> Except as expressly stated above, no rights or licenses from any
>   copyright holder or contributor is granted under this license, whether
>   expressly, by implication, estoppel or otherwise.

Like MIT and BSD-2-Clause and unlike Apache License v2, BSD+Patent is compatible with GPLv2. Like Apache License v2 and unlike MIT and BSD-2-Clause, BSD+Patent avoids leading to potential [patent trolls](https://google.github.io/opencasebook/patents/#express-but-non-specific-licenses).

Licensing under BSD+Patent is an interesting [alternative to dual-licensing under MIT+Apache v2](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/rationale-of-apache-dual-licensing/8952/5).

Answer (score -1):

Another consideration that led me to adopt the 3-clause BSD license for my open source contributions is that, unlike the MIT license, it names the license grantor. Apart from the necessity of doing so to the enforceability of the third clause and to the validity of the copyright declaration included therein, I believe that the license should name the grantor to make it enforceable.

The foregoing is my personal belief; I am not an intellectual property lawyer, regardless of the fact that I am the author of four applications now pending before the USPTO.

Comment: Hi David! What do you mean by "license grantor"? You mean the "copyright holder"? I think it is possible to add a "Copyright mention" on the top of both MIT/BSD before the beginning of the license itself. Most people do that.

Comment: Who else has the legal authority to grant a license?

Comment: Ok, then why do you think it is not enough to have the Copyright notice on top of the license, in the same file? I did not downvote your answer, I am genuinely asking. Besides nowadays with open-source software, copyright owners are often widespread across various contributors, and the copyright notice would need to be modified frequently in theory. It is generally common that the Copyright notice on the license only mentions the initial creator of the project. That doesn't mean that other copyright holders lose their rights - the proof of their contributions is on the VCS like GitHub anyway.

Comment: The issue at hand is not the wording of the license per se, but the need for placeholders in the license URL of a NuGet package. As it stands, there is no provision within the definition of the License URL for a query string to supply values that could fill in the blanks in the generic license displayed by the URL.