# Is the MIT license suitable for documentation?

Tags: mit, documentation

On choosealicense.com, [there's a section that says](https://choosealicense.com/non-software/#data-media-etc):

> Any open source software license or open license for media (see above) is applicable to software documentation

This implies that the MIT license is suitable for documentation.
However, I find it weird that a software license would be applicable to documentation. The [MIT license](https://opensource.org/licenses/MIT) explicitely talks about software. The only part where the documentation appears is on what triggers the license obligations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While re-reading the license again and again, I noticed the slight wording difference that makes it suitable.

> this software and associated documentation files (the "Software")

So when software is spelled with a capitalized "S", it means: software + documentation. And that's the capitalized version that is used in all the rest of the document:

> rights to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell copies of the Software

So yes, the license applies to the documentation too.

Comment: documentation files include Bug (issue) Database?